# lessをつかったとき.zshenvをよみにいきますか？

Tags: zsh

zsh（5。2）を使っています。
そこで`less` (`/usr/bin/less` less458) を使うと、どうやら
`~/.zshenv`をよむようです。

そしてたとえば`~/.zshenv`に`echo hi`のようにあると
`less hogehoge.txt`
をおこなうと`hogehoge.txt`の中身に関わらず
hiが表示されるだけになります。

何がおかしいのでしょうか？

less はMANPAGERにしてあります。

Comment: ファイルをlessで表示した状態で`r`を押すとどうなりますか？ `r`は、画面を再描画します。

Comment: `type less` の実行結果を教えて下さい。

Comment: 報告： Docker上のクリーンなUbuntu 14.04にapt-getでzsh 5.0.2を入れ、`~/.zshenv`を作って実験してみたのですが、同じ状況が再現せず、普通にファイルを閲覧できました。（Dockerでやっているのが悪いのかもしれませんが）

Comment: 関係していそうな環境変数としては `LESS` 及び `LESSOPEN` があります。

Comment: ```r``` をおしても```echo hi```によるhiのみが見えております。
```type less```は ```less is /usr/bin/less```と返します。
心当たりは```pyenv```というソフトですが、.
@nekketsuuu さんは```less```で```~/.zshenv```がよみこまれなかったということでしょうか？当方OSはCentOSです。```LESS```, ```LESSOPEN```はそれぞれ
```-isnMCd -c -m -x4 -R```  ```||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s```となっています。（lessに詳しくないのでこれから調べます）

Comment: `LESSOPEN` が `|| ...` となっていますが、`| ...` ではないでしょうか？(バーティカルバーは2個ではなく、1個だけ)

Comment: 報告： Docker上のCentOS7, zsh 5.0.2でも試してみましたが、Ubuntu同様普通にファイルを閲覧できました。`.zshenv`が読み込まれたかどうかは分かりませんが、echoは無い状態です。ミニマムな構成なので`LESS`も`LESSOPEN`も空でした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。```LESSOPEN```, 二本確かに存在しています

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`less` のソースコードを眺めてみますと、`LESSOPEN` に指定されたコマンドを

```
$SHELL -c cmd
```

として実行しています。

**less-481/filename.c**

```c
public char *
open_altfile(filename, pf, pfd)
       :
{
       :
  if ((lessopen = lgetenv("LESSOPEN")) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  while (*lessopen == '|')
  {
    /*
     * If LESSOPEN starts with a |, it indicates 
     * a "pipe preprocessor".
     */

        :
  len = (int) (strlen(lessopen) + strlen(filename) + 2);
  cmd = (char *) ecalloc(len, sizeof(char));
  SNPRINTF1(cmd, len, lessopen, filename);
  fd = shellcmd(cmd);

        :

static FILE *shellcmd(cmd)
  char *cmd;
{
        :
  shell = lgetenv("SHELL");
  if (shell != NULL && *shell != '\0')
  {
             :
    /*
     * Read the output of <$SHELL -c cmd>.  
     * Escape any metacharacters in the command.
     */
    esccmd = shell_quote(cmd);
    if (esccmd == NULL)
    {
      fd = popen(cmd, "r");
    } else
             :
```

なので、例えば、

```
zsh% SHELL=/bin/bash less filename
```

などとすると `~/.zshenv` を読み込まなくなります。

Comment: 当座この方法で回避したいと思います。```~/.zshenv```を読み込んでいることがそもそも想定外だったため質問させていただいたのですが、たいへん勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。